# Rearrange array with multiple keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [12] => USD
    [13] => 10150.00
    [14] => 9850.00
    [15] => SGD
    [16] => 8015.40
    [17] => 7915.40
    [18] => HKD
    [19] => 1304.60
    [20] => 1288.60
    ...
)
```

What I want to do is arrange it to be like this:

```
Array
(
    [USD] => Array
             (
                 [Buy] => 10150.00
                 [Sell] => 9850.00
             )
    [SGD] => Array
             (
                 [Buy] => 8015.40
                 [Sell] => 7915.40
             )
    [HKD] => Array
             (
                 [Buy] => 1304.60
                 [Sell] => 1288.60
             )
    ...
)
```

I've done a lot of array functions but still stuck with this.

Comment: You need to iterate over it and create desired structure, there is no ready function for that.

Comment: @frozenade, your question being answered, may you please mark one answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Answer (score 5):

If the suite of fields remains the same as:

1. Currency
2. Buy value
3. Sell value

then, you can do:

```
$old_array = array('USD', 123.00, 432.34, 'SGD', 421.41, 111.11);
$new_array = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($old_array); $i = $i + 3) {
    $new_array[$old_array[$i]] = array
    (
        'Buy' => $old_array[$i + 1],
        'Sell' => $old_array[$i + 2]
    );
}
```

Comment: You probably need to do `$i_currency = $old_array[$i]` tho, and then just use `$i` on the buy/sell indexes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Demo](http://ideone.com/uUU83A)

---

```
$data = array
(
    'USD',
    '10150.00',
    '9850.00',
    'SGD',
    '8015.40',
    '7915.40',
    'HKD',
    '1304.60',
    '1288.60',
);

$result = array();

while (is_null($value = array_shift($data)) !== true)
{
    if (preg_match('~^[A-Z]{3}$~', $value) > 0)
    {
        $result[$value] = array
        (
            'Buy' => array_shift($data),
            'Sell' => array_shift($data),
        );
    }
}

print_r($result); // transformed array
```

Comment: That's amazing. +1 for all. Thank you very much for Stéphane Bruckert and Alix Axel. Now, I just convert it to xml service.

Answer (score 0):

Since the structural pattern of your input array is reliable, I can provide a functional approach (no for/while loops, no new variables in the global space).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Mjkus))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        array_chunk($input, 3),
        function($carry, $item) {
            $carry[$item[0]] = ["Buy" => $item[1], "Sell" => $item[2]];
            return $carry;
        },
        []
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'USD' => 
  array (
    'Buy' => '10150.00',
    'Sell' => '9850.00',
  ),
  'SGD' => 
  array (
    'Buy' => '8015.40',
    'Sell' => '7915.40',
  ),
  'HKD' => 
  array (
    'Buy' => '1304.60',
    'Sell' => '1288.60',
  ),
)
```

[array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) creates an array of 3 consecutive elements from your input array.
[array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) is used to form a new, associative output array.